# Fixed DIV scrolling through floated ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

Help me please with an advice how can I code something like this? Do not downvote me for codeless question. I tried a lot of different methods but they are ugly and I don't want you to rewrite my hindu's code, just give me an advice of what should I use to reach the solution. If it will work without JS and hacks - would be awesome. Thank you so much for trying to help me!!!
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get the middle div to be fixed in a way that when you scroll down, everything re flows around that div?

Comment: Mmm.. Yes, I think so.

Comment: Can you help me to figure out why there (http://jsfiddle.net/Q78SH/) green block goes upper the grey one? Diasable and enable position: relative; for ".centered" while it's 3x3 on preview. We have 8 grey divs but when I make .centered relative and move to the center, that grey block which was in center - doesn't move at all...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the green box is on top of the centered grey box because it is positioned relatively. When you do that, the space it would take up, ie that top corner, still takes up that space, so you are just covering that center block, not making this `.center` block stay in the center and everything flow around it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position read up on postion relative here. I don't think that is your solution. I would look into this gridster.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code its really hard to give practical code solution, BUT you really should check out the [Gridster.js](http://gridster.net/).

The demo is really close to what you asked for.
My advis would be to use Gridster, and scroll() function to make to the combination you need.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look and try to use it as well.

Comment: you welcome, keep me updated if you need more help :)

Comment: mike - don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` on your "this div must be fixed" `<div/>` should get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately with position fixed block number 5 will be under it.

Comment: I see now how the surrounding blocks need to interact. You may want to clarify that requirement in your question. To have the adjacent elements shift around, you'll need to use a combination of `position: absolute/relative` and some JavaScript to poll your scroll position.

Comment: Due to my poor english I decide to do kinda image-question... I'm sorry for that.